# How to reproduce and test the function of memory barrier in X86 Linux

Tags: linux, memory-barriers

Memory barrier is to ensure the ordring of memory access, and there are several blogs describe what it is.
But I am still trying to find a typical (man forged) case to show its value.  I tried the codes in this link https://blog.csdn.net/zhangxiao93/article/details/42966279.
But I am not sure if that code is correct to show the wrong result without using memory barrier.
Any link or code snippet is appreciated.

Comment: https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/ has an x86 asm example of the standard store-buffer / StoreLoad reordering litmus test.

Comment: Great, this is what I really need.